# Syntax issue on rest object's callback

Tags: php

I had issues settiing a route registration function until I remembered to add the namespace to it:

```
add_action('rest_api_init', '\DelayedCoupons\registerDummyRoute');
```

But now I believe I have the same issue in a class and I can't seem to solve it. What error am I making below?

```
// main file
namespace DelayedCoupons;

require_once ('adminSettingsArea/ApiController.php');
use \admin\controllers\ApiController;

$apiController = new ApiController();
add_action('rest_api_init', [$apiController, 'registerDummyResponse']);


// class file required above
namespace admin\controllers;

class ApiController extends \WP_Rest_Controller {
  protected $namespace = 'delayedCoupons';
  protected $version = '1.0';

  protected $urlBase;

  public function __construct() {
    $this->urlBase = $this->namespace . '/' . $this->version;
  }

  protected function respondWithString() {
    wp_send_json('dummy response');
  }

  public function registerDummyResponse() {
    register_rest_route($this->urlBase, 'dummy', [
      'methods' => 'GET',
//      'callback' => '\admin\controllers\ApiController\respondWithString'
//      'callback' => 'ApiController\respondWithString'
      'callback' => 'respondWithString'
    ]);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The callback has to be public:

```
public function respondWithString()
```

And in your `register_rest_route()` call, set the `callback` to `[ $this, 'respondWithString' ]`:

```php
register_rest_route( $this->urlBase, 'dummy', [
  'methods'  => 'GET',
  'callback' => [ $this, 'respondWithString' ],
] );
```